# Simple AutoClicker clicks only once instead of number of times

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ok, so I try the code a simple autoclicker. I have a button, I want to click on it, then wait a bit, maybe 500ms and then the program should click 10 times on the current cursor location with 300ms delay between each click

for some reason it does the click just once and not 10 times like I wanted

private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a small delay between mouse down and mouse up. Also your code, if working properly, would click twice per loop. So 20 times.

```
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
```

Comment: I thought this might be the issue too... The OS probably doesn't register the 2 mouse events right next to each other

Comment: thx!! works perfectly. can you explain why do you need to put the delay between down and up?

Comment: @GhnbTrcv I don't have an educated answer for you, I only know this from experience. But I'm thinking Zakk is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: not working properly. I want 300ms delay between every click